# Reference request: Introductions to current mathematics derived from / related to gauge theories (in physics)

Tags: mathematics, specific-reference, gauge-theory

I was searching for introductions to current mathematics derived from / related to gauge theories in physics.

Can someone suggest some good references?

E.g.

*[Topics in Physical Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848829388) by K. Marathe*

*Audio, video, and other non-text resources are also welcome.*

Comment: @Qmechanic: The question you cite is physics-specific. This question is math-specific. - cheers

Comment: I'm not sure how up-to-date you mean by "current", but generic references on gauge theory-related mathematics I've used are [Nakahara](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Geometry-Topology-Physics-Graduate-Student/dp/0750306068), and [Eguchi Gilkey Hanson](http://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/GT/EGH.pdf)